# How to use locators of Selenium for tabs within Angular application

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I am new to Selenium with Java.

As per the requirement I need to access a TAB within my Angular application.

```
<a _ngcontent-ng-c689374991="" data-val="Dreams" routerlink="/dreams" data-toggle="tab" href="/dreams" role="tab" class="active"><span _ngcontent-ng-c870109355="" class="slanted-text">Dreams</span></a>
```

Every time I try to locate the TAB, it gives error stating "**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:**"

Tried the following ways using xpath, but unable to achieve the result:-

1. Using Full XPath

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-top-nav/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/a")).click();
```

2. Using XPath

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"offcanvasExample\"]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
```

3. Using Router Link

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@_ngcontent-ng-c870109355-router-link='/dreams']")).click();
```

4. Using HREF

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'href=/dreams')]")).click();
```

Could someone please guide me?

Comment: Try XPATH of //a[@href='/dreams']

Comment: @pcalkins - Still the same error.

Comment: Does an iframe appear in front of it?

Comment: be sure to use a webdriverwait...  angular tends to load DOM objects after page load and/or update them frequently.